# ESP32 USB-C connectivity issues with CP2102N

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, usb, esp32, cp2102

[image: Schematic of the ESP32 + CP2102N section]
**Context**: I designed some PCBs for a device that uses the [ESP32-PICO-D4](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-pico-d4_datasheet_en.pdf) as a backbone connected with USB-C via the [CP2102N](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/cp2102n-datasheet.pdf). I manually assembled my PCB incrementally as to detect problems immediately as they come. Unfortunately, I did not get very far. I have only assembled the ESP32 section of the PCB and I cannot flash any code to the chip.

**Problem:** I am unable to flash any code to the ESP32 chip, As far as I can tell, my schematic seems to be correct and in-line with existing devices. When trying to upload any code, the Arduino IDE gives me the **No serial data received** [error](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/esp32/troubleshooting.html).

I used both [this](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/esp32-pico-kit-v4.1_schematic.pdf) and [this](https://github.com/tinypico/tinypico-hardware/blob/master/TinyPICO%20V2%20Schematics/TinyPICO_V2_C2_Schematic.pdf) schematic as reference, as well as the datasheets of each chip. I don't see how it can be a design issue (provided I'm not missing something)?

**A schematic review would help point me in the right direction** before I turn my troubleshooting aim to the PCB itself or any other "physical" type issues. A second pair of eyes or opinion would very much be appreciated.

**Suspects and Additional Details**:

Under the assumption the schematic is correct, I suspect the following:

- The problem appears to be on the ESP32 side, not necessarily with the CP2102. I don't know how many people here are familiar with [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), but I am using the [espflash](https://github.com/esp-rs/espflash) flash tool to load my Rust code onto the chip. Espflash detects the presence of a CP2102 serial device (so does the Arduino IDE) they just both have problems actually connecting to the ESP32. This for sure indicates some problem with the loading of code onto the ESP32 chip and/or with the RX/TX lines. I test with both the Arduino IDE and espflash.
- I suspect that the problem might have to do with the PCB itself, however (both before manufacturing and after) I made sure to check the routing, DRC, etc. multiple times. When researching about the nature of the error, it does unfortunately give evidence to this suspicion. The *No serial data received* error occurs when there is an issue with the RX/TX lines are not working or the ESP32 can't reset into download mode. I did not see any problems with the PCB visually.
- Improper soldering or some sort of short? This is not the most likely but still something I considered. I verified all solder connections, everything looks good and both the CP2102 and ESP32 are soldered cleanly.
- All voltage levels are where they should be; the USB-C is spitting out ~4.9V (post schottky diode) and the linear regulator is giving me ~3.28V.

I'm not sure how much help this will be, but here is the layout for the ESP32 section of my PCB:
[image: Layout of the ESP32 + CP2102N section]

[image: Larger layout of the ESP32 + CP2102N section]

This is a four layer board; I removed the two middle layers (GND planes) for better visibility.

**Any additional critiques of both the schematic and layout are encouraged!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TXD and RXD are incorrect.

Both example schematic links confirm it.

TXD of one chip must be connected to RXD of another chip.

And since critique was requested, why bother putting 3 resistors, 10k+10k+100 ohms in place of just one, and USB data lanes are differential pairs and should be routed the way differential pairs are supposed to be routed.

Comment: Unbelievable that I did that. Thank you so much, case closed I guess!

Comment: @BlueOyster Oh my, I'm sorry for you, and you have my full sympathy. It happens to everyone. But it is painful indeed.

Comment: All good, I don't ever expect the first spin to work out so I go into this already assuming I made a mistake. I just wish the mistake was something less...ridiculous.